# Using JQuery to replace multiple instances of HTML on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've made a script which copies the `alt` attribute of an image and puts it into a `<span>`. It also formulates the information divided by a hyphen. It works like a charm, but only with one image.

I would also like to wrap a `<div>` around the image to prevent unnecessary markup.

#### Script snippets:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hoejre">
    <p>
         <span class="alignright">
             <img src="tommy_stor.jpg" alt="Name - Title" 
                  width="162" height="219" />
             <span></span>
         </span>
   </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var alt = $("#hoejre p span img").attr("alt");
$('#hoejre p span span')
 .html("<strong>" + alt.replace("-", "</strong> <em>") + "</em>");
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="alignright">
    <img height="219" width="162" alt="Name - Title"                  
         src="tommy_stor.jpg">
        <span>
            <strong>Name</strong><em>Title</em>
        </span>
</span>
```

How do you I repeat the effect on several images, with different information within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img.some-class').each(function () {
    var self = $(this);

    self.wrap('<div />').after('<span><strong>' + self.attr('alt').replace('-', '</strong> <em>') + '</em></span');
  });
});
```

Make sure that you assign a common class to those images you want this to work for, and alter "some-class" appropriately.

I wasn't so sure what 'unnecessary markup' you wanted removed, but the above code is a good starting point.

Comment: Hi Matt

I need the seperator "-" to be replaced more than once. How do you do that??

alt="First - Second - Third - Fourth"

Thank you in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that assumes all the `<img>` elements are contained in a single element.

```
$('#box img').each(
  function(index,element){
    // do your magic here for
  }
)
```

The function inside `jQuery.each()` would be the same if you used this or Matt's approach. to expand Matt's approach to work with the HTML you provided:

```
$('span.alignright').each(
  function(index,element){
    var img=$(this).find('img');
    // do your magic here
  }
);
```

Which approach you take depends on your situation.